# How to do huge data migrations on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

Hi we have an app on Heroku, that is changing a lot from time to time. This means that we need to do some pretty big migrations on our data now and then. My question is - how to do this efficiently and without having to keep a terminal connection open for several hours doing a `heroku run rake db:migrate` and with as little downtime as possible.

And just to make myself clear - my question is NOT about writing the migrations themselves - it's only about running them on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
heroku console
::MIGRATION_PIPES = IO.popen3("rake db:migrate")
```

But be sure to take the servers offline beforehand - the question is wherever it's possible to  connect if the servers are offline.

About performance: are your migrations SQL or Ruby-heavy?

Comment: SQL Heavy - I'm wondering if it's possible to use rake heroku scheduled for the task?

Comment: And - btw - what is this actually doing? Can I just close the window/my local computer after i have fired that line?

Comment: It creates a subprocess and runs rake in there. It should actually be possible to load the `Rakefile` and run it via `Rake::Task#[]`, and do that via `MIGRATE_THREAD = Thread.new { <task here> }` in `heroku console`. But be aware that's risky. Why not run the heroku command in a screen on a stable machine?